# AWS ECS Fargate service is getting scaled up despite no autoscaling policies being defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I have an ECS cluster and service running in AWS. CPU usage is typically around 5-10% but once a month or so it may briefly (for a minute or two) peak to 70%+. I've noticed that when this happens, another instance of the service gets spun up and then the old instance is shut down a couple minutes later. This has caused problems because the service was never designed to run more than 1 instance, and the two concurrent instances compete for resources and cause race conditions while working on the same data. I'm trying to understand why it's scaling and how to configure it not to.

In the console the service says it has 1 desired task and `No Auto Scaling resources configured for this service.` The cluster has no default capacity provider strategy and no capacity providers specified. I've been going through AWS documentation to try and find where else autoscaling could be defined for a Fargate service, but can't find anything. What am I missing?

Comment: Server management questions belong on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

Even without autoscaling configured, ECS will replace your task if it becomes unresponsive. It sounds like something is causing the CPU to spike in your application, at which point it becomes unresponsive, leading ECS to think that your application has crashed.

By default, when ECS replaces your task it will first start up another instance of the task and wait for it to become healthy, before terminating the unhealthy task. To change this behavior you need to change the `maximumPercent` value in the [ECS deployment setting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DeploymentConfiguration.html) to `100`, and the `minimumHealthyPercent` to `0`, which will tell ECS that at most you want 100% of your desired task count of `1` running during a deployment. To satisfy this configuration, ECS will first shut down the unresponsive task before starting up the new one.

Comment: Thanks! How exactly does ECS check task health? We have no explicit healthcheck defined anywhere (such as an API endpoint or anything like that). We are not using a load balancer and have no target groups (the service polls a queue). And during high CPU usage it's still running and processing data. Ideally I'd like to modify the health check to not report these cases as unhealthy, there is no reason to replace the instance with a new one.

Comment: Here are some details to read regarding that: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/a-deep-dive-into-amazon-ecs-task-health-and-task-replacement/ however none of them really seem to apply to your scenario. Are you absolutely certain your container isn't exiting?

Comment: Quite certain, we discovered this by accident because some data got corrupted and turned out it was processed concurrently by two instances that stepped on each other's toes. I can see in the logs that the second instance came online and was actively polling about 90 seconds before the first instance started a graceful shutdown.

Also, in the service deployment log I see `service MyService has started 1 tasks: task 456` and then timestamped 1 minute later `service MyService has stopped 1 running tasks: task 123`

Comment: I wish I could help you more with that. There many be more details in the ECS service and task UI detailing why ECS shut down the service, although you may need to wait for it to happen again to capture that info in the AWS console before it disappears. Regardless, ECS is going to replace your tasks occasionally when Amazon needs to do maintenance to the underlying computer, so you need to modify those settings I mentioned to ensure you never have more than one task running at a time when that occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update those settings, that's good advice. I'll keep looking and ask on AWS forums as well, see if anyone has some other ideas.